# Design web application REST APIs to save the state

Tags: java, web-services, rest, web-applications, api-design

I have to design **REST APIs** to save the state of my web application.
My web application may contain multiple webflows and each webflow may contain multiple pages. So, I need an API that can save/retrieve the data pagewise.

There are few ways to design the endpoint :

```
1) /app/{app_name}/webflow/{flow_name}/page/{page_name}   
    Request Body : application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    page_data : {...json ..}
    page_data_type : JSON -- define the page data type

2) /app/{app_name}/webflow/{flow_name}?page={page_name}   
    Request Body : application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    page_data : {...json ..}
    page_data_type : JSON ---- define the page data type

3)/app/webflow/page/
    Request Body : application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    app_name : text
    flow_name : text
    page_name : text
    page_data : {...json ..}
    page_data_type : JSON -- define the page data type

4) All the above 3 ways but to remove app from the uri      
       and add it to the request parameters.
```

What is the most appropriate way to design this ?

Answer (score 0):

Since it is considered good practice to put all identifying a resource data to a URL and all details data of a resource to only put to payload, **first option** seems to be best approach.

Comment: Could you explain how is it better than option 1

Comment: I meant option 1, updated my answer. When it comes to #2, I'd suggest avoiding approach like this since actually it is payload too what is placed after `?`.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to have the pages accessible beyond the context of a webflow, I'd recommend two urls (assuming you are approaching it as a REST style API)

```
/app/{app_name}/webflow/{flow_id}

/app/{app_name}/page/{page_id}
```

This way you can alter the page independently of the webflow.

each page could return a list of the URLS to webflows it participates in, and each webflow can return a list of URLs to its current collection of pages.

This also opens up the ability to perform move operations in one request, an update to the item that conceptually contains the sub-items.

```
 GET /app/app_1/webflow/flow_1
    (content) Pages = [ page_1, page_2, page_5 ];

 POST /app/app_1/webflow/flow_1 
    (content) Pages = [ page_1, page_4, page_5 ];

 GET /app/app_1/webflow/flow_1
    (content) Pages = [ page_1, page_4, page_5 ];
```

With your current approach, moves can only be performed by two subsequent calls

```
 GET /app/app_1/webflow/flow_1
    (content) Pages = [ page_1, page_2, page_5 ];

 DELETE /app/app_1/webflow/flow_1/pages/page_2

 PUT /app/app_1/webflow/flow_1/pages/page_4

 (and I don't even know where to specify the ordering)
```

Remember, this is the API.  It is just a means of making the data accessible.  Don't get all tied up trying to make the API reflect the underlying data structures too closely.  If you make the binding explicit, sometimes you can find yourself in situations where the underlying data structures cannot be updated easily because it would create a large amount of complications in the API.

Finally, you might want to consider doing the same thing with {app_name}, if it makes sense.

Comment: How will I GET the details of a page for a given webflow ?

Comment: @VineetSingla HTTP GET the webflow, look at its return value.  It contains the data structure that details the pages.  Then HTTP GET the detail for each page.

Answer (score 0):

You typically want to deliver "discoverability" - which means you want to be able to browse the tree. For instance, `/app/{app_name}/webflow/` should list all the webflows, `/app/{app_name}/webflow/{flow_name}/page` should list all the pages etc.

That strongly suggests option 1 is better - it's much more logical to follow that URL structure throughout.

Answer (score 0):

Since your 'page' has a direct relation with the resource so it should be in the path so first one will be the best approach.